# Do unapplied Boolean modifiers affect render times?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, modifiers

I was wondering this, because I did a cut on a lot of meshes and if I want to move one of them, my pc will slow down by a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The viewport has to recalculate and redraw multiple times to give you a real-time display of your changes.  When rendering, this should only happen once per frame during the initial scene build, so the difference should be negligible.